# Open the most recently created spreadsheet with a partial name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to writing macros and VBA stuff so I could use some help figuring this out! I have an Excel spreadsheet that is used to send out daily "huddle" notes for my shift at work. My goal is to have a button you can click that load's the schedule for the week so people know what their assignments are. There is a folder that contains Excel .csv files with our weekly schedule in it for each shift. There are multiple files with similar names, but the end changes based on what week the schedule is for. For example there might be the following .csv files in that folder:

```
1st_Shift_01Jan2023
1st_Shift_08Jan2023
2nd_Shift_01Jan2023
2nd_Shift_09Jan2023
```

I would like to have a macro that when clicked, opens up the most recently made file that is applicable for my shift (2nd shift), so that I may copy what is in the most recent schedule file and paste it into our daily notes.

Before, we just had one workbook with the schedule in it that would be updated. This is no longer what we use for schedules, so I have to change the macro. Now with the multiple files, I am unsure how to get the most recent workbook for the relevant shift to open. Here is the code for the former macro I had used:

```vb
Sub ScheduleTuesday()

    Dim HuddleNotes As Workbook
    Dim ThisWeekSchedule As Workbook
    
    Set HuddleNotes = ThisWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ThisWeekSchedule = Workbooks.Open("S:\Systems\Schedules")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ThisWeekSchedule.Activate
        Sheets("Schedule Input").Activate
        Range("A1:E29").Select
            Selection.Copy
            
    HuddleNotes.Activate
        Sheets("Schedule").Activate
            Range("A1:E29").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
    ThisWeekSchedule.Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'm thinking I might have to use the Directory function? But I'm really new to VBA and haven't used it before and am not familiar with how. Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

I could not type the code in the comment space, so I'm putting it here. Sorry if this isn't ideal, I wasn't sure where else to put it. It is saying no file exists. The file is in the correct folder, however, and contains "2nd_shift" at the beginning of the file name, so I'm unsure why it thinks it doesn't exist. Any help?

Sub Schedule()

```
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileDate As Date
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim Shift As String
Shift = "2nd_shift"

FolderPath = "S:\Systems\Schedules\"

MostRecentFile = ""
CurrentDate = Date

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & Shift & "*.csv")
Do While FileName <> ""
    FileDate = FileDateTime(FolderPath & Shift & FileName)
    If FileDate > CurrentDate Then
        MostRecentFile = FolderPath & FileName
        CurrentDate = FileDate
    End If
    FileName = Dir
Loop

If MostRecentFile <> "" Then
Workbooks.Open FileName:=MostRecentFile
End If
```

End Sub